# Passing & in URL variable with the help of urlencode

Tags: php, url, url-encoding

I have done `urlencode` of the variable before passing to the URL

http://example.com/Restaurants?alias=F%26B

But when I try to print like in the page

```
 $alias =  rawurldecode($_GET['alias']);
 echo $alias;
```

it prints only `F`. How to solve this?

Comment: mod_rewrite can actually decode URLencoded ampersands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt that `$_GET['alias']` exists when requesting a URL with the query `aliasF%26B`. It’s rather `$_GET['aliasF&B']` that’s getting populated.

In this case you need to use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get the full query.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not using the query string "correctly."  It should be in `key=value` pairs.  I would look at using `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to get your information instead.

Comment: i tried to print like echo $_SERVER['alias'];  but not printing anything

Comment: No no, QUERY_STRING is a keyword that defines the information after the ? in your URL.  This would equal "alias=F%26B"

Comment: hey i have few things to explain over here . basically i have .htaccess entry like

[CODE] RewriteRule ^Restaurants/(.*)$ /restaurant_rating.php?alias=$1 [L][/CODE]


so i pass like 
[CODE]http://abc.com/Restaurants/F%26B  [/CODE]
which gets converted to 

[CODE]http://abc.com/restaurant_rating.php?alias=F%26B[/CODE]

internally .

so when i tried directly to use 
[CODE]http://abc.com/restaurant_rating.php?alias=F%26B[/CODE]

and print alias . it prints properly but when i use 

[CODE]http://abc.com/Restaurants/F%26B  [/CODE]

and print alias it prints only F .how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Hmm.  Sounds like the RegEX for your Rewrite Rule isn't working.  This might be better as a separate question.

Comment: Wait, I think I know what is happening!  What is the output of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'].

Comment: its printing q=restaurant_rating.php&alias=F&B

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to urlencode the pair. You only need to urlencode name and a value as such:

Wrong:

```
urlencode('aliasF=B')
```

Correct:

```
urlencode('aliasF') . '=' . urlencode('B')
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK `$_GET` are already decoded.

See [php.net](http://es.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST 
>   are already decoded. Using urldecode()
>   on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST
>   could have unexpected and dangerous
>   results.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to solve this problem by using a different encoding system specific for your situation:

```
function encode($string)
{
  $result = str_replace("|","||",$string);
  return str_replace("&","|20",$result);
}

function decode($string)
{
  $result = str_replace("|20","&",$string);
  return str_replace("||","|",$result);
}
```

This will basically create a separate escaping system using the '|' character. That character can be anything you normally don't use and isn't an field separator.

Here, Apache won't transform the URL to something different, thus voiding the conversion. Also browsers won't transform it.

Mind that you would `decode($_GET['alias'])` and `encode()` the url that the user is pressing or the script is following.